# When deploying Django application on cpanel, application does not connect to static files

Tags: python, django, cpanel, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy django application from cpanel. I have managed to deploy the site and everything works apart from the static files part, because my website loads without any styling. My settings.py part looks like this :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets'),
]

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

When I run command on cpanel terminal command "python manage.py collectstatic", It runs fine and copies over the files however website loads without styling. Also my base html looks something like this (in case I need to change something there however on local server everything was running fine):

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>About</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,200,300,400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- {% static 'website/css/owl.carousel.min.cs' %} -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'website/css/animate.css' %}">
```

Comment: Django does *not* serve static files in production.

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production

Comment: I have seen this documentation and I still don't get it. Are you able to translate it to human language or just give some example how should go around it?

Comment: I guess the part I don't understand is "Configure your web server to serve the files in STATIC_ROOT under the URL STATIC_URL. For example, here’s how to do this with Apache and mod_wsgi."

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, I have learnt that I need to use WhiteNoise library and then make some tweaks to settings.py file and voila! everything works